# How to change the name of Firefox desktop shortcut icon to website?

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, firefox-for-android, app-icons, 8.0-oreo, usability

I long press the icon but only delete action exists there of the icon. 
I press it but it goes to Firefox. 
I create another one but it does not allow me to rename the icon.

OS: Oreo 8.0
Phone: Oneplus 3T

Comment: What kind of icing is this? What action do you want to take place when you press it?

Comment: @Abochur This is about having a shortcut icon to a website. Not the default Firefox internet browser icon.

Comment: I haven't used Firefox, but in chrome when you add to homescreen then it gives you the option to rename it. After you save it, there is no option to change the name. So i suggest you save it again with the new name

Answer (score 0):

*A bochur*'s differential solution

> I haven't used Firefox, but in chrome when you add to homescreen then it gives you the option to rename it. After you save it, there is no option to change the name. So i suggest you save it again with the new name

Answer (score 0):

Ditto on above answer, for me Chrome offers the option but my other browser (Samsung) does not. Other sites say Android OS itself does not offer renaming of icons, so renaming icons must be done by an app.